# Word break Chrome issue

Tags: css, word-wrap, word-break

I have a word that contains "-" in it (pre-balancing) that I don't wont to be separate in two lines.

In Google chrome The word is divided in two lines:

```
something something something pre-
balancing
```

and I want it to be:

```
something something something pre-balancing
```

or:

```
something something something
pre-balancing
```

For other words which don't have "-" works fine.
I have this issue only for chrome browser. In all the other browser that I've tested seems to be working fine.

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 4):

Use a non-breaking hyphen `&#8209;` html entity instead.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap a `<span>` tag around your long word that contains hyphen. And apply CSS as below.

```
<p>something <span class="nowrap">pre-balancing<span> something something something</p>
```

---

```
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Or use the non breaking hyphens within HTML: `&#x2011;` or `&#8209;`
*(Although I prefer CSS)*